# NSXMLParser parse() works only once

Tags: ios, xml, swift, parsing

I'm reading from an XML feed to populate a tableView and I'm using NSXMLParser to parse the XML. Everything works fine the first time I parse the data and I get the table populated like I expect. I then set a timer to update the data from the server on a regular basis. When the timer triggers, I use the exact same method to parse the same XML feed another time, and then it always fails: parser.parse() returns false, but no errors are reported. I can get the line number and column where it fails, but the data is often no different than it was was the first time it parsed the XML (and it worked at that time).

I declare the parser in my TableViewController:

`var parser = NSXMLParser()`

In ViewDidLoad I configure it:

```
    let url: String = "http://www.deltatao.com/clanlord/status/cldata.xml"

    let urlToSend: NSURL = NSURL(string: url)!

    parser = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL: urlToSend)!
    parser.delegate = self
```

In ViewWillAppear I call it and set the timer:

```
    parseClanlordInformation()
    // this will remove the previous timer
    timer?.invalidate()
    // now start a timer to regularly update the data from the server
    startTimer()
```

And here is the function that call parse():

```
func parseClanlordInformation() {

    // reset players list
    players.removeAll()
    // Stop the previous parsing operation in case it was still running
    parser.abortParsing()
    // rebuild the list from scratch
    let success: Bool = parser.parse()

    if !success {
        let error = parser.parserError
        let line = parser.lineNumber
        let col = parser.columnNumber
        print("XML parsing failed at \(line):\(col): \(error?.localizedDescription)")
        print(players.count)
    }

    if parser.parserError != nil {
        print("Error: parse failure!")
        print(parser.parserError)
    }

    myTableView.reloadData()


}
```

And the timer calls the same function:

```
func startTimer() {
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(updateInterval, target: self, selector: #selector(TableViewController.parseClanlordInformation), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

And the XML Parser delegates are set up like this:

```
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {

    currentElement = elementName
    if elementName=="exile" || elementName=="race" || elementName=="name" || elementName=="sex" || elementName=="profession" || elementName=="clan"  {
        if elementName == "exile" {
            foundNewPlayer = true
            currentPlayer.reset()
        }
        passData = true
    }
}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {

    currentElement = ""
    if elementName=="exile" || elementName=="race" || elementName=="name" || elementName=="cost" || elementName=="description" {
        if elementName == "exile" {
            foundNewPlayer=false
            players.append(currentPlayer)

        }
        passData=false
    }
}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {

    if foundNewPlayer {
        switch currentElement {
            case "name":
                currentPlayer.name = string
            case "race":
                var race: String
                if string == "of the People" {
                    race = "Fen'neko"
                } else {
                    race = String(string.characters.dropFirst(2))
                }
                currentPlayer.race = race
            case "sex":
                currentPlayer.genre = string
            case "profession":
                let prof = String(string.characters.dropFirst(2))
                currentPlayer.profession = prof
            case "clan":
                currentPlayer.clan = string
        default: break

        }
    }

 }

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, parseErrorOccurred parseError: NSError) {
    print(parseError.description)
    NSLog("failure error: %@", parseError)
}
```

When I run the app the table fills up with the data normally, then when the first update triggers parser.parse() returns false at line 80, column 1 or thereabout.

Why does it work only once? Is there some reset I'm supposed to do that I forgot?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: FYI - you really need to refactor your code so the remote data access and XML parsing are done on a background thread.

Comment: I agree re background network request and the recommendation to instantiate a new `NSXMLParser` for each parse. As an aside, never assume that the contents of a particular element will be returned in a single call to `foundCharacters`. All of the logic inside `foundCharacters` belongs in `didEndElement`. `didStartElement` should initialize a string variable, `foundCharacters` should merely append to that string, and `didEndElement` should then perform all of the logic interpreting the string and acting upon that.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I will look into putting that in a background thread and put my logic in didEndElement as you suggest. Very informative, I appreciate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that a given instance of `NSXMLParser` can only be used once. Create a new instance each time you wish to parse again.

```
func parseClanlordInformation() {
    // reset players list
    players.removeAll()
    // Stop the previous parsing operation in case it was still running
    parser.abortParsing()

    // Setup new parser
    let url: String = "http://www.deltatao.com/clanlord/status/cldata.xml"
    let urlToSend: NSURL = NSURL(string: url)!

    parser = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL: urlToSend)!
    parser.delegate = self

    // rebuild the list from scratch
    let success: Bool = parser.parse()

    if !success {
        let error = parser.parserError
        let line = parser.lineNumber
        let col = parser.columnNumber
        print("XML parsing failed at \(line):\(col): \(error?.localizedDescription)")
        print(players.count)
    }

    if parser.parserError != nil {
        print("Error: parse failure!")
        print(parser.parserError)
    }

    myTableView.reloadData()
}
```

This also means you can remove the parser setup in `viewDidLoad`.